# how to send http request to a server from the chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am very new to the hyperledger fabric and even blockchains. I am wondering if i can send a http request from the chaincode. Basically before transaction i want to verify some data. Data server is located outside of the fabric network.

So basically scenario is that once a party started the transaction process,  chaincode first verify that the assets are delivered or not. Then engage in the transaction. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The chaincode itself should not send any network requests because it can lead to Non-deterministic response from chaincode. For example what if new block is generated with information that asset is "not delivered", but later, we will try to re-play this transaction to verify entire ledger's consistency and the answer will be "delivered" ? 
The hash for this block will be different and entire chain will get into inconsistent state.

Fabric V1 proposes another [approach](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/proposals/r1/Next-Consensus-Architecture-Proposal.md):

> Then, the peer forwards internally tran-proposal (and possibly tx) to the part of its (peer's) logic that endorses a transaction, referred to as endorsing logic. By default, endorsing logic at a peer accepts the tran-proposal and simply signs the tran-proposal. **However, endorsing logic may interpret arbitrary functionality, to, e.g., interact with legacy systems with tran-proposal and tx as inputs to reach the decision whether to endorse a transaction or not.**

Comment: @ sergey can you help me on this thread -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974189/smart-contracts-using-chaincode

Comment: My actual requirement is that i want a database. Before A pays to B, A must verify a password provided by B. A need to match this password into database. A must only pay after the password match.

Comment: @RisabhSoni Complex entitlements/permissioning systems cannot be solved by querying an external DB. The entitlements/permissions must be placed onto the chain (perhaps using a different chaincode) and queried for on-chain (using a cross-chaincode query).